# How to determine what invoice numbers total to 0

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd been trying to figure out how to figure out which invoice numbers with the same ID are equal to 0. I have more than 300,000 entries in Excel and I have to weed out all excel invoice numbers with the same ID that total of all invoices amount is 0. I tried the sum if but it sums up the total of all invoices and not just the one that equal to 0.

For example:

[image: See Table]

In these examples, Invoice #s 15, 100, 18, 106, 17, 12 & 14 total to 0. Invoice #s 900 & 985 are equal to 0 & Invoice #s 101 & 168 are equal to 0. Is there a formula that will point out which invoice #s with the same ID total to 0?

I would appreciate any information. Thank you in advance.

[image: See Table]

Comment: Are the lines pertaining to one invoice always consecutive.

Comment: yes, how do you know that the -50 applied to invoice 12 and not invoice 14 or some other one? Perhaps eliminating all ID that equal zero will give you a subset that is easier to work through. The you'll need some other set of assumptions to get you through the rest...

Comment: create a key in a helper field by concatenating `ID` and `Invoice Number` then in next field do `SUMIF([KEY_FIELD],[@[KEY_FIELD]],[AMOUNT])` and remove/ignore rows with result `0`

Comment: Hi @GraceBI ,, in fact there are two rows has values below ZERO -50 & -120,, if you wanna check 1 to 1 then  simply use `=C2=0 for ZERos & `=C2<0` for negative values `=C2>0` for +ve,,,the formula will return TRUE & FALSE accordingly...!! Cell references are adjustable.

Comment: ,, **Cont,,** another is, if U wanna get Summary that out of 30000 rows how may Invoice has ZERO then U need to workout with an array (CSE) formula,,, confirm through comments then I'll show you how !

Comment: What I am looking for is to find out which invoice #s with same ID where total of amounts is equal to 0. For example 50 - 50 + 75 - 120 + 10 + 30 + 5 equals 0.

Comment: 50 - 50 is 0 | 75 - 120 + 10 + 30 + 5 is also 0 | so you have 2 set of answers?

Comment: If ID is in A column, amount is in C column you can enter this formula: =IF(A2=A1,C2+D1,C2) in D and it will return 0 at each expected point. How do you want the output to identify the invoice numbers? I can do it using VBA but am not sure how to do it using formulae, and need to know how you want the result to look.

Comment: @harrymc No, invoice #s are not always consecutive. Some invoice #s within the ID were generated  years ago and some this year.

Comment: @Justin Doward, Looks like the formula works only if the offsetting invoices are on the next row. I am hoping to have all invoice numbers that total to 0 under the same ID to be highlighted. In the examples: Invoice #s 15,100,18,106,17,12,14,900,985,101& 168 will all be highlighted. Can we have this done thru VBA?

Comment: “I'd been trying to figure out how to figure out which invoice numbers with the same ID are equal to 0.” You need to show your work here if you expect people to help you. This site does not provide step-by-step tutorials based on open-ended questions.

Comment: Solving your problem requires trying a lot of permutations. That's not something you could do with formulas. Maybe a macro could solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated but not perfected the code, if the poster is still interested and would like to clarify if this outcome will work for them I will finish things off.
As mentioned previously,
This link:
https://thedailycpa.com/identifying-excel-entries-that-add-up-to-a-specific-value/

has the solution for the individual IDs, then:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643134/vba-sub-not-defined-for-solver
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498429/loop-with-solver-vba

start to point toward the VBA solution.

Once you have activated the solver addon as outlined in the first link (it comes natively with excel so does not need to be downloaded) you can run the code as follows in a module:

```
   Sub SolverMacro(Add1 As String, Jval As Long)

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheet1
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheet2
Dim MyStr As String, MyCol As Long
Dim c As Range
mycount = 1

Do While ws2.Range("H4") > 1 And mycount < 5

    'Solver section
    '--------------------
        SolverReset
        SolverOk SetCell:="$H$3", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Add1, _
            Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Add1, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$4", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="1"
        SolverSolve userfinish:=True
        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1 ', ReportArray:=Array(1)
     '--------------------
    'Loop identifies all invoices found in this solve and copies to a string then deletes the row
        MyStr = "Total to 0: "
        For i = Range(Add1).Cells.Count + 1 To 2 Step -1
            If ws2.Range("D" & i) = 0 Then
                ws2.Range("D" & i) = 1
                GoTo MyNxti
            Else
                MyStr = Trim(MyStr & " " & ws2.Range("B" & i) & ", ")
                ws2.Range("A" & i).Resize(1, 5).Delete xlUp
            End If
MyNxti:
        Next i
    ' ---------------------------
        MyCol = ws2.Cells(Jval, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 'identifies last used row.
        If Trim(MyStr) = "Total to 0:" Then GoTo MyExitLoop
        ws2.Cells(Jval, MyCol) = Trim(MyStr)                                  'pastes string containing invoices that have added to zero
        Add1 = "D2:D" & ws2.Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
        mycount = mycount + 1
Loop
MyExitLoop:
        Add1 = "D2:D" & ws2.Range("D2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
        MyStr = "Outstanding: "
        For Each c In ws2.Range(Add1)
                MyStr = MyStr & ws2.Range("B" & c.Row) & ", "
                ws2.Range("A" & c.Row).Resize(1, 5).Clear
        Next c
        MyCol = ws2.Cells(Jval, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 'identifies last used row.
        ws2.Cells(Jval, MyCol) = MyStr                                  'pastes string containing invoices that have not added to zero
        MyStr = vbNullString
End Sub
Sub ExtractorSub()
mystart = Time
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Declare variables
'---------------------------------------
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheet1
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheet2
Dim MyUniqueArr, MyFullArr
Dim x As Long, y As Long, MyRW As Long, Add1 As String, Add2 As String
ws2.Range("G1") = "Target"
ws2.Range("H1") = 0
ws2.Range("G2") = "Sum"
ws2.Range("H2") = "=SUM(INDIRECT(""$E2:E""&COUNTA($E:$E)+1))"
ws2.Range("G3") = "Difference"
ws2.Range("H3") = "=SUM(INDIRECT(""$E2:E""&COUNTA($E:$E)+1))"
ws2.Range("G4") = "Sum of Bin"
ws2.Range("H4") = "=SUM(INDIRECT(""$D2:D""&COUNTA($D:$D)+1))"

'------------------------------------------
'use autofilter to create unique list on sheet 2
ws1.Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws2.Range("J1"), Unique:=True
'create array of full list and unique
MyUniqueArr = Application.Transpose(ws2.Range("J2:J" & ws2.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
MyFullArr = Application.Transpose(ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row))
' place header on unique list
ws2.Range("Extract") = "ID Number"
'Loop through all unique ID numbers
For x = LBound(MyUniqueArr) To UBound(MyUniqueArr)
    For y = LBound(MyFullArr) To UBound(MyFullArr)
        If MyUniqueArr(x) = MyFullArr(y) Then
            MyRW = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ws1.Range("A" & y).Resize(1, 3).Copy ws2.Range("A" & MyRW).Resize(1, 3)
            ws2.Cells(MyRW, 4) = 1
            ws2.Cells(MyRW, 5) = "=$C" & MyRW & "*" & "$D" & MyRW
        End If
    Next y
    Add1 = "D2:D" & MyRW
    Call SolverMacro(Add1, x + 1)
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Code took: " & Time - mystart & " seconds to complete."

End Sub
```

A working example is at the OZGRID thread here: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/1229924-how-to-determine-all-invoices-with-the-same-id-that-equal-to-0/&postID=1251250#post1251250

To run the code as it is written you need to create a workbook with sheet1 and sheet 2, then copy your data to sheet1 with the columns A,B & C containing the IDs, Invoice # and $ amount.

Then open sheet 2 and run the code, either by placing a button on the page linked to the ExtractorSub or by running the code from the module.

The code will then create a list of unique ID numbers on sheet 2, fill columns G & H rows 1 to 4 with some headers and formulas. It then copies all of one the matching IDs for each unique ID sequentially and runs a solver loop on them identifying all that add to 0. I have limited the number at the moment to 4 possible solutions but if I look at this again I think there is a way to get stop the loop when no solutions are found which removes this requirement.

At the moment the input:
[image]

results in this output:
[image]

I am not sure how it will go on 300,000 rows, it might be best to try on a few thousand and see how long it takes to do the solves then increase or just keep copying a few thousand at a time. I can probably make the code more efficient in parts but the solver itself will probably take the majority of the time.

Comment: Hi Justin, Thank you so much for your help. When I do it, it gives me this error "Compile Error Sub or function not defined" & highlights this yellow - Sub SolverMacro(Add1 As String, Jval As Long).   However, it still provided the data                                                               
 Target 0  ID Number
12345 15 -120 1 -120  Sum 0  12345
12345 18 5 1 5  Difference 0  65013
12345 106 10 1 10  Sum of Bin 7  98562
12345 100 -50 1 -50     
12345 17 30 1 30     
12345 14 75 1 75     
12345 12 50 1 50

Comment: Hi Grace, if you can get me a copy of your worksheet I can implement the code correctly. It works fine at my end. I am not sure how to share files here, if you want to open a thread at https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?board/75-excel-vba-macros/ you can upload a and download files, I can post the solution back here once it is complete.

Comment: Hi Justin, I did submit a query. I was able to attach a spreadsheet. Thank you very much